# How to search a string for 1st occurrence of ":/" and then search all other occurences of the found substring inclusive ":/"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, windows, tex

**A little explanation:**

I have a string like (from a commandline programm execution `kpsewhich -all etex.src`):

```
c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/etex.srcc:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/plain/etex/etex.src
```

This string consists of 2 or more concatenated file paths, which are to be separated again.

**Dynamic search pattern: `c:/`**

The files are always on the same volume, here `c`, but the volume name has to be determined.

Is it possible to do something like this with an RegExp?

I could split the string according to the actual filename `etex.src`, but is the other approach possible?

**Update:**

The RegExp as follows

```
(.+?:[\/\\]+)(?:(?!\1).)*
```

meets my requirements even better. [How to disassemble a string with CaptureGroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211051/how-to-disassemble-a-string-with-capturegroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe this expression would be somewhat close to what you might want to design:

```
c:\/.*?(?=c:\/|$)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IKT2Gx/1/)

Comment: Thank you Emma Peel! To search over multiple lines I had to change the dot against [^] e.g. `c:\/[^]*?(?=c:\/|$)`. Integrated in node.js with `var paths = filename.match(/c:\/[^]*?(?=c:\/|$)/g)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want this RegExp to retrieve but if you want to get the array of file paths then you can do it with `/(?<!^)[^:]+/g` regex:

```js
// in node.js
const str = 'c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/etex.srcc:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/plain/etex/etex.src'
const paths = str.match(/(?<!^)[^:]+/g)
// [
//   "/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/etex.srcc",
//   "/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/plain/etex/etex.src"
// ]
```

This RegExp searches for a sequence of symbols which don't include `:` and which don't start at the beginning of the string (this excludes `c` volume or any other volume name)

Comment:  I want exactly @Emma's solution, but you showed me how to include it into node.js => +1.