# How to disassemble a string with CaptureGroup "(.+?:[\/\\]+)"?

Tags: regex, regex-group

A given string:

```
dec:/file1.texdec:/file2.srcdec:/file3.ltx\ndec:/file4.dtxdec:/file5.insdec:/file6.src
```

contains concatenated file paths.

(The length of the volume name (here: dec) is variable. Pay attention to the line break in the string.)

With the RegExp **`(.+?:[\/\\]+)`** (without g and without m options) I get the CaptureGroup \1  `dec:/`.

(If the volume name is only `c` the CaptureGroup contains `c:/`. With path containing `\` instead of `/` the CaptureGroup also contains `dec:\` or `c:\`.)

**How can I match the substrings:**

```
dec:/file1.tex
dec:/file2.src
dec:/file3.ltx
dec:/file4.dtx
dec:/file5.ins
dec:/file6.src
```

**with this CaptureGroup `(.+?:[\/\\]+)`?**

I have prepared the following
**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/HAh3a3/5)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want it ?`(.+?:[\/\\]+)(?:(?!\1).)*`

[This is a demo on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/HAh3a3/6)